# Ошибка в программе С++ после вывода результата

Tags: c++, память, сборка

[image]

При выполнении ,а конкретно после вывода результата выводит ошибку и каждый раз другую.и
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам стоит подавать код в вопросе в текстовом варианте.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос код в нормальном текстовом виде. Смотреть на эти мрачные картинки (а тем более перенабирать код) невозможно!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы неверно выделили память - не

```
int*Num = new int[s];
```

а

```
int*Num = new int(s);
```

Т.е. вы выделили в памяти **один** `int` со значением `s`, а пишете в результате за границу выделенной памяти...

Answer (score 0):

Вы вышли за пределы выделенного размера памяти.

```
int* Num = new int(s);
```

Выделяет память размером `sizeof(int)` и инициализирует ее значением `s`
Выделяя память как `new`, освобождаете как `delete`, а при `new []` освобождаете как `delete[]`. Чтобы выделить память под весь массив, необходимо сделать следующее:

```
int* Num = new int[s]();
```

Comment: спасибо большое